# How to get foreign key linked values while using generic repository and unit of work patterns with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I am new to Entity Framework Core 7 and ASP.NET Core 7 MVC. I am learning the concepts using the Northwind database. I am using a generic repository and UnitOfWork pattern on top of EF Core for data access.

I have created a `ProductsController` and in the view, I want to display all rows of the products in a grid view along with the corresponding category name and supplier name as the `Products` table has `Category ID` and `Supplier ID` as foreign keys.

In the pure EF, I could have used `.Include` to get these two values. However, it's not available in the generic repository pattern. I'm sharing a relationship diagram of these three tables here:

[image]

Code:

```
// GET: ProductController
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var products = _unitOfWork.Product.GetAll();
    return View(products);
}

// Product model
public partial class Product
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Product Name")]
     public string ProductName { get; set; } = null!;

     public int? SupplierId { get; set; }

     public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Quantity Per Unit")]
     public string? QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
     [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
     public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }

     public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
     public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
     public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; }
     public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

     public virtual Category? Category { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; 
        } = new List<OrderDetail>   ();

     public virtual Supplier? Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

In the `UnitOfWork` pattern, these three tables are available individually. Essentially I want to know how to get the Category Name and Supplier Name from the `Products` collection.

Comment: Can you share your code? You probably have to build LINQ queries specific to your needs.

Comment: Better do not use Generic repository pattern. `DbContext` is already UoW, `DbSet` is already repository. You just add another abstraction layer with new bugs and limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the UnitOfWork pattern, these three tables are available
> individually. Essentially I want to know how to get the Category Name
> and Supplier Name from the Products collection.

Well, as you have `Product` class and along with this class you have navigation class those are for instance as `Categories` and `Suppliers`, which has foreign table relationship with `Product` class
**Navigation class**

```
public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string? CategoryName { get; set; }
    }


public class Suppliers
    {
        [Key]
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }
        public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string? ContactName { get; set; }
    }
```

**How To Load Related Entities From Navigation Table In Unit Of Work Pattern:**

In your scenario, we can extent our `GenericRepository` To Product Repository then we can use `.Include` object which help to query data from related table property which would be more convenient and efficient. In your scenario,  When we will query upon `Product` table at the same time we would like to fetch data related to other table as well right, so have a look below:

**UnitOfWork Repository For Product:**

```
public class ProductRepository : GenericRepository<Product>, IProductReposiotry
    {
        public ProductRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, ILogger logger) : base(context, logger) { }
        public override async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> All()
        {
            try
            {
                var products = context.Products.Include(cat => cat.Category).Include(sup=>sup.Supplier).ToList();
                return await dbSet.ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Repo} All function error", typeof(ProductRepository));
                return new List<Product>();
            }
        }
    }
```

**UnitOfWork DbContext:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Suppliers> Suppliers { get; set; }
       
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>().ToTable("Categories");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Suppliers>().ToTable("Suppliers");
           
        }

    }
```

**Note:** Please be sure about the `Northwind` database,property and your class follow same case.

**UnitOfWork Controller:**

```
public class UnitOfWorkProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<UnitOfWorkProductViewController> _logger;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public UnitOfWorkProductViewController(
            ILogger<UnitOfWorkProductViewController> logger,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var products = await _unitOfWork.Products.All();
            return View(products);
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProjectName.Models.Product>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ProductId
            <th>ProductName
            <th>Supplier Name
            <th>Category Name
            <th>UnitPrice
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ProductId</td>
                <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                <td>@item.Supplier?.CompanyName</td>
                <td>@item.Category?.CategoryName</td>
                <td>@item.UnitPrice</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ Join method to join the three tables and then project the result into a model object with properties for the Category Name and Supplier Name.

```
var result = from p in _unitOfWork.Product.GetAll()
    join c in _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll() on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
    join s in _unitOfWork.Supplier.GetAll() on p.SupplierId equals s.SupplierId
    select new {
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    c.CategoryName,
    s.CompanyName
    };
    
return View(result);
```

In the view, you can access the CategoryName and SupplierName properties of the model object. Hope this helps.